# Sample/example for LsaCallAuthenticationPackage Windows API to get information about MSV1_0 in C#

Tags: c#, .net

what kind of struct need to use to get MSV1_0 challenge by calling LsaCallAuthenticationPackage API in C#. my sample code is below.

```cs
UInt32 msvAuthPackageId;
using(OSCalls.LsaStringWrapper msvPackageName = new OSCalls.LsaStringWrapper("MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0")) {
  status = OSCalls.LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage(lsaHandle, ref msvPackageName._string, out msvAuthPackageId);
  Console.WriteLine("NtlmLogon status check again after LsaLookupAuthenticationPackage {0} ", status);
  if (status != OSCalls.WinStatusCodes.STATUS_SUCCESS) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception((int) OSCalls.LsaNtStatusToWinError(status));
}
```

Status is a success but protocolReturnBuf value is empty (always getting zero value and returnBufLen is showing 12)

where authPackage, I am using the below struct to build the pointer and using MSV1_0_PROTOCOL_MESSAGE_TYPE.MsV1_0Lm20ChallengeRequest to get the challenge

```cs
public struct MSV1_0_LM20_LOGON //
{

    public MSV1_0_PROTOCOL_MESSAGE_TYPE MessageType;   
    public LSA_UNICODE_STRING LogonDomainName;
    public LSA_UNICODE_STRING UserName;
    public LSA_UNICODE_STRING Workstation;
   
}
```